# Dimension of direct product of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

> What is the dimension of $\mathcal {V\oplus W}=\{(v_1,\dots,v_n,w_1,\dots w_m):(v_1,\dots,v_n)\in\mathcal V,(w_1,\dots w_m)\in\mathcal W\}$?

Let $\{b_i\}, i=1,\dots,n$ be a basis for $\mathcal V$ and $\{c_j\}, j=1,\dots,m$ be a basis for $\mathcal W$. Form $(b_i|0,\dots,0)$ where there are $m$ $0$'s and $(0,\dots,0|c_j)$ where there are $n$ $0$'s. I show that the set of these two collections of vectors is a basis for $\mathcal {V\oplus W}$.

Span: Any element $(v_1,\dots,v_n,w_1,\dots w_m)=(v_1,\dots,v_n,0,\dots,0)+(0,\dots,0,w_1,\dots w_m)$ can be written as a linear combination of $\sum_{i=1}^na_i(b_i|0,\dots,0)+\sum_{j=1}^m(0,\dots,0|c_j)$, hence the set spans $\mathcal {V\oplus W}$.

Linear independence: Assume $\sum_{i=1}^na_i(b_i|0,\dots,0)+\sum_{j=1}^md_j(0,\dots,0|c_j)=0$, then we must have $\sum_{i=1}^na_i(b_i|0,\dots,0)=0$ and $\sum_{j=1}^md_j(0,\dots,0|c_j)=0$. But $\sum_{i=1}^na_i(b_i|0,\dots,0)=0$ only if $\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i=0$ and $b_i$ are linearly independent so $a_i=0$. Similarly $d_j=0$. Therefore the vectors are linearly independent.

Hence the set is a basis and $\dim(\mathcal {V\oplus W})=n+m$.

Is the proof and conclusion right?

Comment: Assuming your dimensions were finite to begin with, sure.